# How to enable/disable input field in a table row in javascript without affecting other row(s)

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a dropdown menu followed by a text input field. The input box is disabled by default. Selecting a specified option ("OTHER") from the menu should enable the text field.

Note: The user can add multiple row(s) if he clicks on the icon(+). The other row(s) will not be affected when a certain row selects "OTHER". Only the row(s) having the option "OTHER" will be enable.

```
<tr id="dataRow">
    <td>+</td>
    <td>-</td>                                           
    <td>
        <select onChange="checkOption(this);">
         <option value="A">Option A</option>
         <option value="B">Option B</option>
         <option value="C">Option C</option>
         <option value="OTHER">Other</option>  
        </select>
    </td>                            
    <td><input id="inputTextBox"></td>  
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function checkOption(obj) {
        var input = document.getElementById("inputTextBox");
        input.disabled = obj.value != "OTHER";
}
```

Sample:

```
First Row: Selects OTHER (inputTextBox is enabled)
User add another Row: Selects Option A (inputTextBox is disabled)
User add another Row: Selects OTHER (inputTextBox is enabled)
```

The HTML is something like this when multiple row(s) is generated. Sharing the same ids, options..

```
<tr id="dataRow">
        <td>+</td>
        <td>-</td>                                           
        <td>
            <select onChange="checkOption(this);">
             <option value="A">Option A</option>
             <option value="B">Option B</option>
             <option value="C">Option C</option>
             <option value="OTHER">Other</option>  
            </select>
        </td>                            
        <td><input id="inputTextBox"></td>  
    </tr>
<tr id="dataRow">
        <td>+</td>
        <td>-</td>                                           
        <td>
            <select onChange="checkOption(this);">
             <option value="A">Option A</option>
             <option value="B">Option B</option>
             <option value="C">Option C</option>
             <option value="OTHER">Other</option>  
            </select>
        </td>                            
        <td><input id="inputTextBox"></td>  
    </tr>
<tr id="dataRow">
        <td>+</td>
        <td>-</td>                                           
        <td>
            <select onChange="checkOption(this);">
             <option value="A">Option A</option>
             <option value="B">Option B</option>
             <option value="C">Option C</option>
             <option value="OTHER">Other</option>  
            </select>
        </td>                            
        <td><input id="inputTextBox"></td>  
    </tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and can you explain what specific problem you have?

Comment: I have tried the javascript function edited above..

Comment: where is `locateFrom` element. also can show an example of `<select> `tag values.

Comment: why do you use the word `dynamically` in the title? The word has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @user3864004 so if the client selects `other` you want to disable the input element right? Is that it?

Comment: @NewToJS, Yes. But take into consideration that the row(s) are incremental, the client may add multiple rows by clicking and icon(+). and the input element has the same id. My worry is when the 1st row input is disabled, when the user selects Option A in the 3rd row, the 1st row might be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the selected value and disable the input if the client selects `other` this will work.

```js
function checkOption(obj) {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputTextBox");
    if(obj.value=='OTHER'){
        input.disabled=true;
    }else{
        input.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

```html
<select onChange="checkOption(this);">
<option value="A">Option A</option>
<option value="B">Option B</option>
<option value="C">Option C</option>
<option value="OTHER">Other</option>  
</select>
<br>     
<input id="inputTextBox">
```

---

**Or**

---

a new option with the value of other is created and appears at the top of the select. You can give your select an ID and call this function and it will check the selected option after the dynamic option has been added.

```
function checkOption() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputTextBox");
    var Index = document.getElementById("Options").selectedIndex;
    if(document.getElementById("Options")[Index].value=='OTHER'){
        input.disabled=true;
    }else{
        input.disabled=false;
    }
}
```

---

```
<select id="Options" onChange="checkOption();">
```

> **Using selectedIndex**
>
> document.getElementById("Options")[0] => A - Option A
>
> document.getElementById("Options")[1] => B - Option B
>
> document.getElementById("Options")[2] => C - Option C
>
> document.getElementById("Options")[3] => OTHER - Other

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes. But take into consideration that the row(s) are incremental, the client may add multiple rows by clicking and icon(+). and the input element has the same id. My worry is when the 1st row input is disabled, when the user selects Option A in the 3rd row, the 1st row might be enabled or all the input field for every row might be enabled also.

Comment: @user3864004 ID's should be unique and you have edited your question after i posted this answer.

Comment: user clicks (+) to add rows, not to add options to the select.

Comment: @user3864004 well the problem you have is multiple elements using the same `id`. ID's should be unique, hence being used to identify a specific element. This wasn't in your original question. If you keep changing the question each time a person submits an answer you'll find people won't bother to help you anymore.

Comment: apologies for changing the question. I just want that the content is clearly enough to understand so I updated it and provide examples.

Comment: Well you need to use unique ID's this can cause problems when it comes to using javascript.

Comment: How can i use unique ID's if each time the (+) icon is click and it adds another row? Initially, the page has only 1 row in the table.

Comment: Start the first id as something0 and increment when you add a new one, something1 something2 something3...  that would be one way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks @NewToJS.. appreciate your help. May I have a sample so I can better understand? I am new to JS.

Comment: How are you currently creating a new row? If you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to give me a working demo i will see if I can edit it to increment the id's.

Comment: that isn't creating a new row when the icon(+) is clicked.

Comment: I don't have the function for that because this is created somewhere (a framework).

Comment: So you don't have access to whatever it is used to create a new row in your table? If you can't get access to that I cannot help you with the changes made in your question.

Comment: Yes. That's right..:(. Maybe we can add a two row instead? [http://jsfiddle.net/66sog9sb/]

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks nothing like the source code in the question. You said new rows are created using the same input ID's as the first one and cannot be changed. Show me how and where this is done. If you can't then I cannot help you. Show me fully functioning code with the icon(+) that creates the new row in the table with the copy of the inputs that use the same ID's (As shown in your updated/edited question)

Answer (score 0):

Is `jQuery` an option?

If yes use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

According to docs it binds event even to not yet existing elements.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Simply use a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what exactly you are trying to achieve but if its just enabling/disabling the text field something like this in your checkOption function should do the job:

```
function checkOption(obj) {
  if (obj.value == "OTHER"){
    if( document.getElementById("inputTextBox") != null)
      {
        document.getElementById("inputTextBox").disabled = false;
      } 
  }
  if (obj.value != "OTHER")
  {
    if( document.getElementById("inputTextBox") != null)
      {
        document.getElementById("inputTextBox").disabled = true;
      } 
  }
```

Comment: I will try this out. But what if I have added a new row with a value not equal to "OTHER", will the first inputTextBox enabled?

Comment: CheckOption function is called only when new dropdown option is selected so other rows unless they call that same function should not effect the text field.

Comment: other rows call the same function because the user has the option to add multiple row. And the row(s) have same set of ids, same set of select options. Just a copy of the 1st row

Comment: I personally think having elements with same id's on one page is bad practice so I would develop my code to avoid that situation.